# destination table updated tmap talend

Tags: mapping, talend

I'm developping a job that transfer data from an old table to a new one .After mapping almost of  the source  fileds in tmap with their destinations , the destination table was changed and the names of fileds of the destination table were changed also .How can i do update my tmap without recreating the mappings?

Comment: If the target fields are not the same, I don't see how you can avoid redoing the mapping, as the mapping has eventually changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue once, I guess you can't.